# Flutter: How do I change/toggle the text/name of a button dynamically on pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

Beginner here. Couldn't find a comprehensible answer to dynamically changing the text of a button on here or anywhere else, only changing text of another widget. :(

I would love the Text on the button to change when you click it. To be super clear, the button would load with text fetched from Firebase, but for now just the Text 'Title A' will be fine. Then when a user clicks it, it changes to the Text 'Title B'. And be able to change back again on click.

How would I do that?

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 250.0,
                child: FlatButton(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: So, the button text would change to from Title A to title B and back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic String and a boolean to toggle between 2 variable on button pressed:

```
String buttonText = "Text 1";
bool isChanged = true;

FlatButton(
  child: Text(buttonText)
  onPressed() {
    isChanged = !isChanged;
    setState(() {
      isChanged == true ? buttonText = "Text 1" : buttonText = "Text 2";
    });
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks for this Dung Ngo. This doesn't seem to work for me. The button isn't changing either way. :(

Comment: @nerdMonkey I've put the code in dartpad, you can check and apply it to your code: [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b3ccb26497ac84895540185935ed5825)

Comment: You are right! Absolutely my fault, I misread the code, thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

title String init and use setState function

```
String buttonText 

        Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 250.0,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          buttonText = 'your Want Text';
                        });

                      },
                      child: Text(
                        buttonText,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use dynamic variable String.

```
String textTitle = 'TitleA';
            
        FlatButton(
         onPressed:(){
          setState(){
           textTitle = 'TitleB';  //text you want to change
          }
        }
         child: Text(textTitle)
       );
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for getting back to me. How does it change back again?